# How can I generate a 13GHz sinosoidal wave with a multipilier circuit?

Tags: rf, oscillator

I have heard with some multiplier circuits we can obtain a low phase noise oscillator. For example, by using a 100MHz OCXO and a multiplier circuit with a multiplier factor of 100 we can obtain a 10Ghz with low phase noise. My question arose on how to generate a 13GHz signal with this procedure when the multiplier factor is not common.

Comment: maybe it's possible to generate some original signal that you'll multiply with common factor? I mean, you don't change multiplication factor, but you change the original signal. Not 100MHz but whatever will be necessary

Comment: A PLL has an arbitrary counter, you can change 100MHz with 130MHz, if you are able to make 10Ghz from 100Mhz.

Comment: Thank you very much, I need to use an 86.6 Mhz oscillator to create a 13Ghz with 150 factor. But this value is not common in the market and is not easy to create an 86.6Mhz easily without any crystal quartz circuit.(they have more than -110dBc/Hz at 1Khz below 100Mhz)

Comment: @Parisa could you really add, in numbers, what "low noise" means at 13 GHz. I'd concur with Bimpelrekkie, you think this is easy, where in reality it's really hard, but maybe your definition of "low noise" is different from ours. So: What noise is acceptable to you for your 13 GHz tone?

Comment: Generally you can get any oscillator frequency you want, if you can convince the vendor that you're business is worthwhile (for example, you're going to order at least 10's of devices) and you're willing to wait (lead times can be 10 - 16 weeks) for a custom part.

Answer (score 7):

> by using a 100MHz OCXO and a multiplier circuit with a multiplier factor of 100 we can obtain a 10Ghz with low phase noise.

You would have to have an **ultra-ultra-low noise 100 MHz signal** to get "low phasenoise" at 10 GHz after multiplication. Also, your frequency multiplier circuit would need to be very good so that it doesn't add noise.

Realize that every time that you **double** a frequency with an **ideal** frequency multiplier (one that adds **zero** noise), your phasenoise will degrade by 6 dB.

So if I multiply a:

100 MHz, PN = -80 dBc @ 10 kHz signal

with an ideal 2x multiplier I get:

200 MHz, PN = **-74** dBc @ 10 kHz signal

This is the reverse of dividing a frequency down, here's an [article](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/white-papers/Clock-Division-WP.pdf) explaining that.

Note that this a **theoretical limit** so there's no way around that, in real life, things are **always worse**.

This is only multiplication by 2, for a multiplication factor of 130 the phasenoise degradation would be **42 dB**. If that gives you "low phasenoise" depends on your needs.

Note that nearly all (integrated in an IC) transceivers work like you describe. A "low frequency" (20 MHz to 100 MHz) crystal oscillator is used to generate a **reference frequency** clock. Then a [PLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop) is used to multiply that clock up to the value that is needed.

The phasenoise will then degrade as mentioned above. However, as long as the phasenoise is **good enough** that is not an issue.

Comment: Excellent response. This is my field, and I would enjoy writing a response myself, but I would just be saying the same things you already have. I would point out that indeed, the 6 dB phase noise hit is a theoretical limit, and in practice we always do worse, but we can actually get very, very close provided the original signal is sufficiently strong. EG, if you look at the phase noise of a source like a PSG, you can really see the almost exactly 6-dB hit you take each time the internal signal chain needs to double the reference again.

Comment: Yes , you are right, But OCXOs are popular for this purpose. For example this:https://www.avnet.com/shop/us/products/abracon/aocjy2-a-100000mhz-f-sw-3074457345625847709/ would be a good selection for creating a 10ghz (-80dBc/Hz at 100Hz) . I need to know how to generate odd frequencies such as 13Ghz with a 100Mhz oscillator.

Comment: As I said before, unless you just need a single stable tone that will never change in frequency, its pretty much impossible to make a oscillator that good without being an absolute expert in the field. 100 000 dollar lab generators can barely mange such low phase noise, and those are designed by some of the best experts in the industry.

Answer (score 0):

This another way to derive it ..    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whispering-gallery_wave

**Whispering gallery waves** have also been observed in the vibrations of soap films as well as in the vibrations of thin plates and gravity waves after a black hole event.

Oscillator stabilised by a frequency discriminator, based on the reflection from an SLC resonator.

"low phase noise signal generators based  on  sapphire “whispering gallery”-mode resonators,  and look  at  the  future  potential  of  these  oscillators  to  meet  the ever-increasing   demands   for   precision   signal   generation   and processing."  **[REF](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mehran_Mossammaparast/publication/4135164_A_review_of_sapphire_whispering_gallery-mode_oscillators_including_technical_progress_and_future_potential_of_the_technology/links/56187e1f08ae044edbad246c/A-review-of-sapphire-whispering-gallery-mode-oscillators-including-technical-progress-and-future-potential-of-the-technology.pdf?origin=figuresDialog)**

[image]

But you can do your homework and read up (after free login)

ref https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228793922_10_GHz_oscillator_with_ultra_low_phase_noise/figures

Carrier suppression oscillator using a microwave interferometer
[image]

Comment: To go much higher in frequencies, we won't be talking about SoS or GaAs pre-scalers  but rather **Plexciton Oscillators with 20 um wavelength** with plasmons and excitons instead of electrons.

Answer (score -1):

There is no magic with multipliers, from what I recall.

If the 100MHz starting signal has 1 picosecond of zero-crossing time uncertainty, then any multiplied energy will have at least that same 1 picosecond of uncertainty.

Thus the time wander remains the same, but because the period (now 0.1 nanosecond and only 1% of the original 10nanoSeconds, if Fout = 10GHz) is shorter, the phase noise has become much worse.

There is a way to overcome this: use a very narrow bandpass filter.

Your question wants 13Ghz final, from 100MHz starting. The integer components are

- 13
- 10 = 2 * 5

Never having implemented a 13X (nor even 2X or 5X), I suggest you examine classic integer_N synthesizers.

Or even FracN systems.

Decades ago, I developed (in 1 micron biCMOS) in a 44-pin IC, with off_chip oscillators, solutions for 900MHz, 1600MHz, 1900MHz, and 2300MHz.

The 900MHz re_used an available 16/17 Prescalar.

The 1600,1900,2300MHz used a new design of 23/24.

We fed into the Frac_N logic at 60MHz+, with F_lock at 13/5 = 2.6MHz. This was a GSM cellsite synthesizer.

Phase noise, first pass, was -86 dBc/rootHertz, producing total integrated phase noise of 8 degrees.

The Frac_N resolution was 1/256 of 2.6MHz, if I recall rightly. Thus settable to about 10KHz.

A big part of the design was planning of PINOUTS and layout, to minimize the crosstalk between regions of the silicon. We burned pins, having at least 5 different VDD/GND pairs. The central Frac_N logic (+5v CMOS) had 200 picoFarads of local VDD onchip filtering, with 10pF at each end of each of the place-route logic layout rows, to ensure those 50 picosecond charge demands were LOCALLY provided. And all the wells for the PMOS also stored VDD charge. As does all the gate_oxide of non_transitioning logic gates.

And there was a 10_ohm resistor between the internal +5volt logic rail, and the +5v package pin, again to slow transients that tried to exit the chip.

Which worked. The PLL spur (at 2.6MHz F_lock) was -105dBc.

The 23/24 prescalar used 0.2 volt logic swings, in a form of current mode logic, everything operating differentially. I recall reviewing the final layout and inserting extra substrate_ties to better ensure the local capture of errant charges.

Also the 23/24 used THREE sets of VDD/GND pins; this produced a VCO load pull of -120 dBc, the lowest the customer had ever seen.

==========================

Given the OP provides no SPECS, I've provided examples of spec facts for both multipliers and PLLs.

I've often seen the curious mind enjoy the details of complete examples, including gotchas.

I appreciate the work of Bimpelrekkie in his multiplier-focused answer.

I note Bimpelrekkie did not address the use of a narrow-band 13GHz bandpass. I would find that to be interesting.

In the PLL work I've done, I concluded the selective consumption of POWER in the right circuits, such as ECL_to_CMOS converter, or in the logic of the Phase Frequency detector (don't charge_starve these), or in the charge_pump steering transistors, is needed.

To summarize, just because your transistors can wiggle at 13 GHz with 1mA, does not mean you can achieve the needed low_phase_noise in that transistor/circuit.

I once advised a company making radios, as they converted from 50_ohm modules to ICs. They had random_noise phasenoise issues and could not diagnose the causes. They had fallen into the trap I expected of such design teams, where the delight of silicon empowerment with low power consumption was their downfall.

Over lunchtime that day, I computed they needed to keep **ALL** the resistors in their CML prescalar to sum up less than 6,000 ohms. That meant all the collector resistors (driven by tail currents) and all the rbb' base_spreading resistors, in about 5 flipflops and 4 gates, had to sum to less than 6,000 ohms.

This was based on an assumed SlewRate in that Prescalar.

Comment: Another confusing/confused answer so I was forced to write a more clear one myself.

Comment: I understand it perfectly, maybe it is lack of reader experience but assumptions are ?? 13GHz prescalar ??

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Maybe you understand because your mind can work in a similar way as analogsystemsrf's mind. Probably my mind works differently as I fail to see the "story" in this answer, to me it looks like a bunch of facts and experiences. I have worked with **extremely** bright engineers that understood things perfectly themselves but were unable to explain that understanding to others. It was simply "too obvious" to them. I'm less bright so I need a more consistent story in order to understand. Maybe that is the case here.

Comment: If you know it, it is understandable but a block diag. Would help others. This gets into the nitty gritty of a x130 multiplier. But faster CCL Saphire prescaler should make this possible other ways.